# How to write and read data at the same time from a PHP Script to an Android device

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have a PHP Script which is used to write data to a MYSQL Database.The Script retrieves the data from an Android app and write it to the database table.What I want is : the PHP script will calculate the count of data in the database table according to the date of entry and pass the count to the Android device according to which I need to do some validations in the Android App.Is it possible to do so in the same script? I mean is it possible to write data to a database table from an Android app on a button click and also read the data from the same script into the App.Can anyone please help me with this?

My PHP Script is:

```
<?php
require "conn.php";
require "SalesLogin.php";

$enquiry = $_POST["enquiry"];
$retail = $_POST["retail"];
$collection = $_POST["collection"];
$booking = $_POST["booking"];
$evaluation = $_POST["evaluation"];
$test_drive = $_POST["test_drive"];
$home_visit = $_POST["home_visit"];
$user_name = $_POST["user_name"];
$update_date = $_POST["date"];
$absent = $_POST["absent"];


$timezone = new DateTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata" );
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone($timezone );
$time =  $date->format( 'H:i:s A' );


$sql = "UPDATE employee_details SET
enquiry_sum = (SELECT SUM(enquiry) +'$enquiry' FROM (SELECT * FROM employee_details WHERE date = CURDATE() AND name = '$user_name') AS x)
WHERE date = CURDATE() AND name = '$user_name'";
$res = $conn->query($sql);

$check = "UPDATE employee_details SET enquiry_target_status = ( SELECT IF (MAX(enquiry_sum) = 52, 'ACHIEVED', 'NOT ACHIEVED') FROM (SELECT * from employee_details WHERE date = CURDATE() AND name = '$user_name') AS Y ) WHERE date = CURDATE() AND name = '$user_name'";
$insert_status = $conn->query($check);


$miss_count = "UPDATE employee_details SET enquiry_target_missed_by = (SELECT (50 - MAX(enquiry_sum)) FROM (SELECT * from employee_details WHERE date = CURDATE() AND name = '$user_name') AS Z ) WHERE date = CURDATE() AND name = '$user_name'";
$insert_status = $conn->query($miss_count);


$mysql_qry1 = "INSERT INTO employee_details(enquiry,retail, 
collection,booking, evaluation, test_drive, home_visit, name, date,time,absent) values ('$enquiry','$retail','$collection','$booking','$evaluation','$test_drive',
'$home_visit','$user_name','$update_date','$time','$absent');";

if($conn->query($mysql_qry1) === TRUE) 
    echo "Your details has been successfully inserted.";

else 
    echo "Error: " .$mysql_qry1. "<br>" . $conn->error;


if($update_date != $date){
$mysql_qry2 = "UPDATE employee_data SET last_updated_date = (DATE_ADD('$update_date', INTERVAL 1 DAY)) WHERE name = '$user_name';";
$conn->query($mysql_qry2);
echo "Date changed," .$mysql_qry2;
} 


$mysql_qry3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) from employee_details WHERE date = '$update_date' and name LIKE '$user_name';";
$conn->query($mysql_qry3);
      if($mysl_qry3 <= 2) 
              {
                   echo "You can login.";
              } 
         else 
              {
                  echo "You cannot login anymore for today.";
             }


$conn->close();
?>
```

I want to check the condition and pass the result for the below part and make validations in Android App:

```
$mysql_qry3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) from employee_details WHERE date = '$update_date' and name LIKE '$user_name';";
$conn->query($mysql_qry3);
      if($mysl_qry3 <= 2) 
              {
                   echo "You can login.";
              } 
         else 
              {
                  echo "You cannot login anymore for today.";
             }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was making is : I did not use "AS" keyword in the PHP Script.

The updated PHP Script is:

```
$mysql_qry3 = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count from employee_details WHERE date = '$update_date' and name LIKE '$user_name';";
$result1 = mysqli_query($conn,$mysql_qry3);

                       $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);
                       $count = $row['count'];

                       echo "Count: " .$count; 
      if($count <= 2) 
              {
                   echo "You can login.";
              } 
         else 
              {
                  echo "You cannot login anymore for today.";
             }
```

This gives the desired result.